# Magento 2 - Simple product Price and description not showing on product page

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, price, simple-product

I tried to add simple product in Magento 2.2.6. Product created successfully but I viewed product detail page, price and short description are missing. I edit my product again and add a attribute option (like color or size) in configure tab. Price and description are now showing after attribute value/option.

Is configurable attribute option is required for also simple product?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning cache and reindexing.

```
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/mangeto indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Already tried these commands. No luck.